# add superior statement in activerecord hash condition

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a hash which contains many conditions. I want to add to it another condition which uses the superior statement how can I do it?

for example:

```rb
// conditions is a hash of conditions
conditions[:id]="> 100"
personels=Personel.find(:all, :conditions=>conditions)
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? also version of activerecord you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Usually (*Not sure if i fully understood your goal*) you store multiple conditions in an `Array` then you simply add more conditions using arrays `<<` append operator, something like:

#### Conditions is an Array:

```
conditions = []
conditions << "id > '100'"
conditions << "NAME LIKE '%#{params[:name]}%'"
#
# ... more conditions here
#
conditions = conditions.join(' AND ')
Personel.where(conditions)
```

#### Conditions is a Hash:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:id] = "> '100'"
conditions[:NAME] = "LIKE '%#{params[:name]}%'"
#
# ... more conditions here
#
conditions = conditions.map{|k,v| "#{k} #{v}"}.join(' AND ')
Personel.where(conditions)
```

Comment: not exacly in a array but in a hash for exmple [:id => 100, :name=>"name" ] all of those are with the statment equal I want to add superior

Comment: sorry about the delay, i've updated my answer to include a `Hash` of conditions case.